# Access: Can Microsoft Access Tables be updated automatically from SQL Server

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm almost completely new to MS Access.  In Access 2013, can tables in Access be automatically updated nightly based on a SQL query?  Or, if I create a table in SQL that's updated nightly, can that update Access tables nightly as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but it is far better to **link** the SQL Server tables in Access.

Comment: OK thanks.  I'm working on learning the basics now.  I just wanted to know if it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can in SQL Server attach an Access database file as a *Linked Server* server object. Then you have access to the tables of that database from within SQL Server.

However, the Access database will often have to be opened exclusively, meaning that it will fail if opened from another application, or - when opened from SQL Server - no other application can get access.